# How to assign columns to new axis using numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-analysis

I need to create a 3D array from a 2D Google spreadsheet using specific column(s) to denote axis. I ultimately need this to use modalities in a tslearn model for time series clustering.

usage_date  Location    Product Revenue
7/12/2021   Portland    A   200000
3/21/2022   Portland    A   300000
3/8/2021    Portland    A   196000
3/29/2021   Portland    A   198000
3/26/2023   Turin           B   100
3/1/2023    Turin           C   200
12/19/2022  Turin           A   100
3/9/2023    Turin           D   100
3/12/2023   Turin           E   75
2/13/2023   Delhi           C   0

Shape of the table is (10,4) without headers but I really need it to be (number of locations, length of time series, number of products) = (3,10,5)

I can add axis to the array via:

```
product_data = product_data.to_numpy()
product_data = product_data[..., newaxis]
```

So my (10,4) becomes (10,4,1), but not sure how to assign columns to axis to get to (3,10,5).

Answer (score 0):

just reshape it to `(3,10,5)`! `product_data.reshape(3,10,5)`

It would be easier to use pandas instead! load your file into pandas and set the index to `date, location, product` (or whatever order you prefer). This creates a series.

After that just run `series.values.reshape(series.index.levshape)`

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ('2023-05-30', 'Product A', 'Location 1', 10),
    ('2023-05-30', 'Product A', 'Location 2', 20),
    ('2023-05-30', 'Product B', 'Location 1', 30),
    ('2023-05-30', 'Product B', 'Location 2', 40),
    ('2023-05-31', 'Product A', 'Location 1', 50),
    ('2023-05-31', 'Product A', 'Location 2', 60),
    ('2023-05-31', 'Product B', 'Location 1', 70),
    ('2023-05-31', 'Product B', 'Location 2', 80),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date", "product", "location", "revenue"])
df.set_index(["date", "product", "location"], inplace=True)
print(df.values.reshape(df.index.levshape))
```

```
>>> df.values.reshape(df.index.levshape)
array([[[10, 20],
        [30, 40]],

       [[50, 60],
        [70, 80]]], dtype=int64)
```